# Searching for a substring match from a hash in Perl

Tags: regex, perl, hash, data-mapping

I have a file that has the substrings that I need to match in a given string. These given strings are taken from another file which has the actual data. This is a column in a csv file. If the given string has any of these substrings it will be marked as TRUE. What is the best way to do this is Perl?

What I've done so far is something like this. There still seem to be some issues:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

if ($#ARGV+1 != 1) {
 print "usage: $0 inputfilename\n";
 exit;
}

our $inputfile = $ARGV[0];
our $outputfile = "$inputfile" . '.ads';
our $ad_file = "C:/test/easylist.txt";  
our %ads_list_hash = ();

our $lines = 0;

# Create a list of substrings in the easylist.txt file
 open ADS, "$ad_file" or die "can't open $ad_file";
 while(<ADS>) {
        chomp;
        $ads_list_hash{$lines} = $_;
        $lines ++;
 }  

 for(my $count = 0; $count < $lines; $count++) {
            print "$ads_list_hash{$count}\n";
       }
 open IN,"$inputfile" or die "can't open $inputfile";       
 while(<IN>) {      
       chomp;       
       my @hhfile = split /,/;       
       for(my $count = 0; $count < $lines; $count++) {
            print "$hhfile[10]\t$ads_list_hash{$count}\n";

            if($hhfile[9] =~ /$ads_list_hash{$count}/) {
                print "TRUE !\n";
                last;
            }
       }
 }

 close IN;
```

Comment: @Ed I have put the code I made. But there are still some errors. But it has quite a few errros.

Answer (score 2):

see [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.21/lib/Text/CSV.pm) - comma-separated values manipulator like

```
use 5.010;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
my @rows;
my %match;
my @substrings = qw/Hello Stack overflow/;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } )  # should set binary attribute.
                 or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag ();
open my $fh, "<:encoding(utf8)", "test.csv" or die "test.csv: $!";
while ( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) ) {
        if($row->[0] ~~ @substrings){ # 1st field 
            say "match " ;
            $match{$row->[0]} = 1;
        }
 }
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();
close $fh;
print Dumper(\%match);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use selectcol_arrayref or fetchrow_* and a loop to get an array of the words to search for. Then build the regex pattern by joining that array with '\b)|(?:\b' and embracing with '(?:\b' and '\b)' (or something better suited to your needs).

Answer (score 1):

Here's some cleaned-up code which will do the same thing as the code you posted, with the exception that it does not print `$hhfile[10]` along with each ad pattern before testing them; if you need that output, then you're going to have to loop over all the patterns and test each one individually in basically the same way that you were already doing.  (Although, even in that case, it would be better if your loops were `for my $count (0 .. $lines)` instead of the C-style `for (...;...;...)`.)

Instead of testing each pattern individually, I've used [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Regexp%3a%3aAssemble), which will build a single pattern which is equivalent to testing all of the individual substrings at once.  The smart match operator (`~~`) in Nikhil Jain's answer will do basically the same thing when used as shown in his answer, but it requires Perl 5.10 or later, while Regexp::Assemble will still work for you if you're on 5.8 or (heaven forbid!) 5.6.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Regexp::Assemble;

die "usage: $0 inputfilename\n" unless @ARGV == 1;

my $inputfile     = $ARGV[0];
my $outputfile    = $inputfile . '.ads';
my $ad_file       = "C:/test/easylist.txt";
my @ad_list;

# Create a list of substrings in the easylist.txt file
open my $ads_fh, '<', $ad_file or die "can't open $ad_file: $!";
while (<$ads_fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @ad_list, $_;
}

for (@ad_list) {
    print "$_\n";       # Or just "print;" - the $_ will be assumed
}      

my $ra = Regexp::Assemble->new;
$ra->add(@ad_list);

open my $in_fh, '<', $inputfile or die "can't open $inputfile: $!";
while (<$in_fh>) {
    my @hhfile = split /,/;
    print "TRUE !\n" if $ra->match($hhfile[9]);
}
```

(Code is syntactically valid, according to `perl -c`, but has not been tested beyond that.)